# Некорректная работа border-radius в Chrome и Opera

Tags: css3

При анимации дочерного элемента он вылазит за края.
В FF все хорошо, в хроме скачки а опера вообще отказывается скрывать. 
Как решить проблему?

http://jsfiddle.net/PULAt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

http://jsfiddle.net/PULAt/1/

Не в наших силах править браузеры.

Comment: интересное решение, спасибо! под мою задачу подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить белую границу либо прозрачную шириной в 1px, но появятся неровности в отрисовки.

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
border: 1px solid #fff;
```

Для Chrome, Вы так же можете попробовать [WebKit CSS Mask](https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/):

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

для вашего примера сработало. http://jsfiddle.net/PULAt/2/